# PhpStorm "Automatic upload failed: connection timed out: connect" ok, but which files exactly hadn't been uploaded?

Tags: phpstorm

How to determine which files weren't uploaded when "automatic upload" fails? Without synchronizing whole project.

The following functions don't answer this question:

1. Recent files
2. Recently changed files
3. Recent changes

I searched for extended event log or error log but without any result.

Comment: You can examine log file: Help -> Show log.

Comment: @Kootli log contains only PhpStorm debug info. No single file name included.

Comment: All "failed" entries should be printed into "File Transfer" window (becomes visible only when first transfer operation occurs). This log is not saved anywhere and info gets cleared on IDE restart.

Comment: Related: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11067